# How to crop white spaces in png images?

Tags: 14.04, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a pair of png images that I want to include in a paper. Here's an example:

[image: graphs with white space below]

Below the image there is a large area of white space. How can I crop this image to get rid of that white space? I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I have tried with `convert -trim` but nothing changed.

Comment: Richard, wouldn't it be more reasonable to have a look at the output options of the programme that you used to generate the plots in the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shotwell photo manager. There is the crop option, in wich you can select a square or unconstrained crop. Select unconstrained and crop.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to generate a trimmed image.

Trimming  different images may raise different problems... We have to tune some parameters. Try:

```
convert input.png -border 1x1 -fuzz 15% -trim output.png
```